# iOS transactions not in SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored state during restore flow

Tags: ios, transactions, in-app-purchase, rmstore

I've been having a lot of trouble with the in app purchase restore flow. It seems that a very small subset of my users cannot restore properly. I used to have my own custom built implementation but I found it harder to debug and decided to switch over to `RMStore`.

This is not a bug with `RMStore` - it has existed before I switched over to using it.

Going through my analytics it seems that some users hit the restore success case BUT never successfully trigger the premium state. Restore code is below.

```
[[RMStore defaultStore] restoreTransactionsOnSuccess:^(NSArray *transactions){
    if ([SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue].transactions.count == 0) {
        [self.tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"RESTORE"
                                                                   action:@"failure"
                                                                    label:@"no_purchases"
                                                                    value:nil] build]];
        [self fail:@"There are no items available to restore at this time."];
    } else {
        // seems to be triggered every time a successful restore made if there are items
        [self.tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"RESTORE"
                                                                   action:@"success"
                                                                    label:@"items_in_queue"
                                                                    value:nil] build]];
        for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
            if (transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored) {
                if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:(NSString*)productID]) {
                    [Utils setPremium:YES];
                }
            }
        }

        [self success];
    }
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    //...
}];
```

My only guess here is that the transactionState of the affected user's transaction is not `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored`. I have confirmed with some of the affected users and they have all purchased the premium version. What other state could their transaction be in?

Should I be finishing any transactions in this case that are not `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored` via `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];`? Would this recover users that were stuck in this state?

**Edit:** This is a non-consumable purchase and the id has been the same since it was created.

Comment: I'm guessing your *premium* IAP is a non-consumable, 1-time purchase? (not a subscription). Also, just for covering all bases: the product ID hasn't changed from a previous app build?

Comment: Good point I should have clarified that. Yes it is a non-consumable purchase and no I haven't changed the product ID at any point

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! At which point are you setting your observer on the `defaultQueue`?

Comment: With RMStore you no longer have to set observer manually as that is done within the library itself. https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore

Before I switched to this lib I was setting the observer in the ViewDidLoad of my Store page